# Problemas al intentar leer archivo con FileReader en Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-metodo

Estoy intentando realizar una lectura de archivo en cliente, donde se debe comprobar que el archivo no es vacío y además tiene la estructura adecuada. Se trata de poder subir y cargar únicamente archivos con extensión .csv y que tengan como cabecera DNI y NOTA; si no cumplen alguna de las dos condiciones, debe aparecer un mensaje de error y mantener el botón deshabilitado. Para realizar esta tarea, he realizado dos métodos en javascript, lo cuales son:

```
    function sePuedeEnviarArchivo(){
    let nombreArchivo = $('file').value;
    let boton = $('bSubirDoc');
    
    if(null == nombreArchivo ||  nombreArchivo.length < 1){
        alert("Debe incluir un archivo, con extensión csv.");
        //boton.style.visibility = "hidden";
        boton.disabled = true;
        nombreArchivo = "";
    }else if(!nombreArchivo.endsWith(".csv")){
    
        alert("No puede subir archivos con esa extensión. La extensión debe ser csv");
        
        //boton.style.visibility = "hidden";
        boton.disabled = true;
        nombreArchivo = "";
    
        
    }else if(nombreArchivo.endsWith(".csv") && !esArchivoConDatos( $('file'))){
        
        //boton.style.visibility = "hidden";
        boton.disabled = true;
        alert("Archivo vacío o no tiene el formato adecuado.");
    }
    else if(nombreArchivo.endsWith(".csv") && esArchivoConDatos( $('file'))){
        boton.disabled = false;
        alert("Archivo con extensión y formato correctos para enviar");
        
    }
    
    
}
function aviso(){
    let nombreArchivo =  $('file').value;
    
    if(nombreArchivo.length < 1 || !nombreArchivo.endsWith(".csv") || nombreArchivo.endsWith(".csv") && !esArchivoConDatos($('file'))){
            
        alert("Debe incluir un archivo con extensión CSV y el formato adecuado");
        
    }
}
function esArchivoConDatos(file){
    
    var resultado = true;
    
    let archivoIntroducido = file.files[0];
    
    
    if(archivoIntroducido.size <= 2){
        
        resultado = false;
    }
    if(!leerFichero()){
    resultado = false;
```

}

```
    return resultado;
}

function leerFichero(){
    
    const DNI = "DNI";
    const NOTA = "RDO.EVALUACION";
    var resultadoLectura = true;
     const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    const result = event.target.result;
    let cannotRead = result.indexOf(DNI) == -1 || result.indexOf(RDO_EVALUACION) == -1
    
    if(cannotRead){
    resultadoLectura = false;
}
  });
  
  return resultadoLectura;
}
```

A estos métodos los llamó desde HTML:

```
<p align="center">
                <br><input id="file" name="file" type="file" class="caja" style="height: 25px;"  accept=".csv"  onchange="sePuedeEnviarArchivo()" />
                <br><input value="Subir Doc." style="background-color: #C0C0C0" type="button" id="bSubirDoc"  onmouseover="aviso()"  class="boton" disabled/>
```

Todo va como se espera, pero a la hora de leer el archivo, no hace absolutamente nada, por lo que no se realiza la validación de la estructura. He estado siguiendo la documentación de FileReader, y no consigo dar con el motivo. ¿Alguien sabe qué está fallando?

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: En la función `leerFichero` nunca lees el fichero

Comment: Hola Yussef. Gracias, pero event.target.result tengo entendido que te devuelve el contenido del archivo cargado. Un saludo, he estado intentando con lo clásico (read, readLine...) sin ningún resultado.

Comment: Pero ese evento no se ejecuta nunca, por que no has cargado el fichero, te falta algo como `reader.readAsText(file)`

Comment: Hola de nuevo. ¿Quieres decir que dentro del evento haga algo como contenidoArchivo = reader.readAsText(archivo) y boolean contieneCabecera = contenidoArchivo.contains("algo")? Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te decia en los comentarios, te falta la función para leer el archivo, como es un CSV (que es un texto) puedes ocupar `readAsText`. Que debe colocarse fuera del evento, esta función es la que hace que el evento gatille.

```js
function readFile(input) {
  let file = input.files[0]; 
  let fileReader = new FileReader(); 
  
  fileReader.onload = function() {
   console.log(fileReader.result);
  }; 
  
  fileReader.readAsText(file);  //<--Esto te falta

}
```

```html
<input onchange="readFile(this)" type="file">
```